# Excel - Pivot Table - Data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create an Excel Pivot table from multiple sheets onto 1 pivot table. The problem I'm having is that I have the data I'm pulling from separated out by week and it isn't formatted as a table. I am including a screenshot of where the source data comes from. Is there any way to get a pivot table to work from this? What I am wanting to do is pull from the LOB column and have a count of the ones listed under there. Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nBVD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just load the three different sheets into PowerQuery (data .. .from table/range .... file ... [x] table has headers .... file ... close and load to ... only create connections) then append the queries (data ... get data ... combine queries ... append ) and load it back to excel as a pivot table (file .. close and load as ... pivot table report)

Comment: Thank you for your response. That did  help. The problem is now it is showing the header for LoB that I have listed in there. Should I do the range over and over to select each "week" in the table I have set up?

Comment: I assume you created the ranges [x] with headers ? Pos the code generated viewed with home. Advanced